# Why am I getting hundreds of syntax errors from cmath.h?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, cmath

I'm doing a project in c++ using OpenGL and keep getting hit with hundreds of syntax errors from cmath.h. The main puzzle is that I'm not even refering to or including cmath at all. I'm using math.h in one or two things but that code was working perfectly before I made recent changes. Going back to the previously working code now shows the same errors so I'm kind of stumped on where to start looking.

Am I missing something really obvious or could this be a Visual Studio 10 issue?

Comment: Sorry, my crystal orb is broken. I'm pretty sure, some library header include does in turn include cmath.h. I suggest you look right before your includes, if there may be a stray brace left open or similar.

Comment: From C to C++, header file name transition is like `<file.h>` to `<cfile>`. Apply that for `<math.h>`, it becomes `<cmath>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because there is no (standard) `cmath.h`

The C math header is `math.h` and C++ also exposes this library but as just `cmath`, however all the elements of it are lifted into the std:: namespace.

In a C++ project you should include the library like so:

```
 #include <cmath>
```

and use it's elements like:

```
 c=std::sqrt(
       std::pow(a,2)
      +std::pow(b,2));
```

or whatever else you have going on.

#### references

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math

Comment: Thank you. I knew it'd be something simple like that.

Comment: Just FYI, in C++11 the names are not required to not be in the global namespace, and in C++03 they were but that rule was frequently broken.

Comment: @SethCarnegie sure, but as a matter of code correctness, using the prefixed names guarenteed to exist is far better practice.

Comment: @NathanHall if this was the correct answer can you please mark it as such to help users with the same problem.